# SQL query to show the difference between multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I am in need of some help in showing all rows that have different dates based on a unique number in a table, below is a dummy table I have created which is similar to the one I need to analyse.

[image]

What I need to show is all rows where the expected date has changed but the VisitNumber is the same, I have highlighted four rows as an example;

The First Entry Was Null
The Second Entry Was 25/04/16
Then the final entry was 24/06/16

Sometimes the there could be an entry where the Visit Number is the same as a row that has changed but the Expected Dates are the same, in this case, I need to ignore them rows.

Additionally, there could be multiple entries with the same Unique ID but the Visit Number is different.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I don't understand this:  "Sometimes the there could be an entry where the Visit Number is the same as a row that has changed but the Expected Dates are the same, in this case, I need to ignore them rows.".  Your data has no such cases, so I'm don't follow the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
SELECT UniqueID, VisitNumber, Min(ExpectedDate), Max(ExpectedDate)
FROM Table
GROUP BY uniqueID, VisitNumber
HAVING Min(ExpectedDate) <> Max(ExpectedDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             min(ExpectedDate) over (partition by UniqueId, VisitNumber) as mined,
             max(ExpectedDate) over (partition by UniqueId, VisitNumber) as maxed
      from t
     ) t
where mined <> maxed and ExpectedDate is not null;
```